# Grok parsing with special characters in message

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack

In Logstash/grok how can I parse messages with special characters in the danish alphabet, such as æøå?

I'm trying to parse the following message (IIS log file):

```
2016-06-12 18:15:10 server01 192.168.10.1 GET /test/charæfoobar pagenumber=2 443 - 192.168.100.31 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:47.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/47.0 https://domain.com/test/char%C3%A6foobar domain.com 200 0 0 5493 559 515
```

With this pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logTimestamp} %{NOTSPACE:server} %{IP:serverIp} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:page} %{NOTSPACE:querystring} %{NUMBER:port} %{NOTSPACE:username} %{IP:clientIp} %{NOTSPACE:httpVersion} %{NOTSPACE:useragent} %{NOTSPACE:referer} %{NOTSPACE:siteDomain} %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER:substatus} %{NUMBER:win32Status} %{NUMBER:bytesSent:int} %{NUMBER:bytesReceived:int} %{NUMBER:timetaken:int}
```

I've been debugging with this tool: http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/ and it seems to choke on the æ character in the message.

I'm using the Filebeat log shipper with the encoding set to UTF-8, and IIS outputs logs in UTF-8 as well. It ships directly to Logstash.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC 1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) on Uniform Resource Locators (URL):

> URLs are written only with the graphic printable characters of the US-ASCII coded character set. The octets 80-FF hexadecimal are not used in US-ASCII, and the octets 00-1F and 7F hexadecimal represent control characters; these must be encoded.

Since the character `æ`, i.e. unicode E6, is in the 80-FF range, it would need to be encoded into the `%C3%A6` hexadecimal equivalent. If your URL was properly encoded to `/test/char%C3%A6foobar` as it is the case in the referrer URL, then grok would parse it properly.

**UPDATE**

If you want to handle those non-ASCII characters, instead of using the `URIPATHPARAM` pre-defined pattern, you can build [your own pattern](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns#) off that one and include the non-ASCII characters you want to consider.

Comment: Interesting. But that is not the case with the IIS log. It's strange that IIS is only enconding the characters in the referrer URL. Would there be any way to handle this using Logstash?

Comment: Thanks Val. I'll try and look into it.